# Avoid matching/replacing custom-escaped part of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am replacing a string with RegEx as follows:

```
var str = "{% {{name}} %}: {{name}}";
console.log(str.replace(/{{([^{}]*)}}/g, "John")) // {% John %}: John
```

I want to use {% and %} to escape anything in between - meaning it should skip the *replace*. So the expected output is: `// {{name}}: John`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: did you want to remove this `{%` also ?

Comment: Yes, it would only be part of the string to indicate that I want to escape whatever is in between. In the end, I want it to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
var str = "{% {{name}} %}: {{name}}";

var data = {
  name: 'John'
}

str = str.replace(/{%(.+?)%}|{{(.+?)}}/g, function(_, $1, $2) {
  return $1 || data[$2]
});

document.write(str)
```